# C++ inheritance and same funciton names

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have this situation:

```
class A
{
  public:
    A();
    virtual ~A();
    void doSomething();
};


class B : public A
{
  public:
    B();
    void doSomething(int parameter);
};
```

If I do the following:

```
int main()
{
  B b;
  b.doSomething();
}
```

It gives me a compile error (no matching function).
How can I solve that without changing the `B` funcion name? `B` derives from `A` so it has also the `doSomething()` function without parameters. Why is it not working?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Virtual functions could come in handy here. Also if you are going to work in object oriented, re-read the function overriding topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, `B::doSomething` **hides** `A::doSomething`.

You might use `using` to resolve your issue:

```
class B : public A
{
  public:
    using A::doSomething;
    B();
    void doSomething(int parameter);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just an alternative to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62020774/8012646) in case you aren't allowed to modify class `B`.

---

If you aren't allowed to modify class `B` for adding `using A::doSomething;` inside the class (as already suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62020774/8012646)), you can take a pointer to the member function `A::doSomething()`, then call it through that member function pointer on the instance `b`:

```
auto fptr = &A::doSomething;
B b;
(b.*fptr)();
```

or simpler, by properly qualifying the member function no member function pointer is needed:

```
B b;
b.A::doSomething(); // calls A::doSomething()
```